# How can I get the time consumed by processes when the system is shutting down?

Tags: shutdown, logs

When shutting down there's a process/daemon/something that freezes and slow down the shutdown process. Before the problem appeared the shutdown took about 15 sec., now it takes like 10 minutes!

I need to 'debug' the shutdown to find which is the problematic guy and kill him!!     ̿ ̿̿’̿̿\̵͇̿̿\=(•̪●)=/̵͇̿̿/’̿̿ ̿ ̿

Comment: At the shutdown screen (the purple one with the Ubuntu logo), you can press space (or down arrow) key, and you will see messages from the shutdown process. The last one when it hangs, which should tell you something like "Shutting down [something]", should tell you what it's doing.

Comment: But, there's no log file where I can analyze that info?